How Were the Seven Nations 'Straight in His (God's) Eyes'?
The very first Rashi in Torah states in part:
הוּא בְרָאָהּ וּנְתָנָהּ לַאֲשֶׁר יָשַׁר בְּעֵינָיו, בִּרְצוֹנוֹ נְתָנָהּ לָהֶם, וּבִרְצוֹנוֹ נְטָלָהּ מֵהֶם וּנְתָנָהּ לָנוּ:
“He created it (the world) and gave it to whom was straight/fit in his eyes. When He willed, He gave it to them, and when He willed, He took it from them and gave it to us …”
It’s a quote that the Jewish people will tell/tells the nations of the world and it’s an idea based on Jeremiah 27.
The particular words וּנְתָנָהּ לַאֲשֶׁר יָשַׁר בְּעֵינָיו,  are 'telling.' God only gives land, and in particular the land of Israel, to those who are ‘fit in His eyes.’ What was initially fit/straight in God's eyes about the inhabitants of Israel – the Seven Nations?
Obviously, only God knows.
Per the Radak (Genesis 10:11):
"ונתתיה לאשר ישר בעיני" (ירמיה כ"ז) והכל לפי מעשיהם כי הוא אל אמונה ואין עול.
and I give it to anyone I please (Jeremiah 27) - and all is based on their deeds because He is a faithful God with no perversion ...
There are lots of nations to choose from. But what of the propriety of God giving the Seven Nations the choicest place on earth?
The R"I B'chor Shor states on:
Deuteronomy 32:8
בְּהַנְחֵ֤ל עֶלְיוֹן֙ גּוֹיִ֔ם בְּהַפְרִיד֖וֹ בְּנֵ֣י אָדָ֑ם יַצֵּב֙ גְּבֻלֹ֣ת עַמִּ֔ים לְמִסְפַּ֖ר בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל׃
When the Most High gave the nations their inheritance, when he divided all mankind, he set up boundaries for the peoples according to the number of the sons of Israel.
ולא רצה להנחילה לשאר אומות שלא יערערו עליה, אלא מסרה לעבדיה⁠{ם} לבני כנען, שאינם יכולים לערער עליה כלום, דמה שקנה עבד קנה רבו (בבלי פסחים פ״ח:), ושמרו אותה עד שבאו אדוניהם ונטלום מידם
(God) He did not want to give it (Israel) to the other nations because they would challenge upon it (Israel's right to possess it). Rather He gave it to their servants - the sons of Canaan. They would not be able to challenge it because what a servant acquired is acquired by his master. They guarded it until their masters came and took it from them.
However, מה שקנה עבד קנה רבו is not the whole story for then we would not need הוּא בְרָאָהּ וּנְתָנָהּ לַאֲשֶׁר יָשַׁר בְּעֵינָיו, בִּרְצוֹנוֹ נְתָנָהּ לָהֶם, וּבִרְצוֹנוֹ נְטָלָהּ מֵהֶם וּנְתָנָהּ לָנוּ

The clock of "who G-d gave what" starts from the era of prophecy, when G-d's will became more apparent.

@Shalom please delineate/define the "era of prophecy"? Adam was a prophet (and rare sources hold that there might have been a pre-Adam world). There was a time when there were millions of prophets. Etc. So, I am not sure what you are referring to.

The phrase might not mean that the recipient of the land is "straight", i.e. right, but it could mean that it is right to give it to that recipient. Admittedly, that's not a strong argument, but that question would be much more answerable; we have an explicit pasuk:

ודור רביעי ישובו הנה כי לא־שלם עון האמרי עד־הנה
But in the fourth generation they shall come back here, for the iniquity of the Emori is not yet full. [Koren trans.]

Hashem is telling Avram that the Benei Yisrael will only return to take the land after the 7 nations’ sin is great enough that they warrant destruction.
The various commentaries, such as Rashi and Ramban there, explain this to mean that Hashem won't destroy a people or strip them from a land unless they have a certain level of iniquity, some adding that that is because Hashem gives them an opportunity to repent (a classical Torah principle, brought by Chizkuni there).
One could argue that the "lack of iniquity" is functionally equivalent to "merit", but Rabbi Henkin does find some bona fide merit for some of the 7 nations:

פרוש אחר, אשכל ענר וממרא היו בני ברית אברהם ולכן זכותם היתה יתירה על
זכות שאר ז' העממין
Another interpretation: Eshkol, Aner, and Mamre were allies of
Abraham, and thus their merit was greater than that of the other seven
nations

This was counted as merit towards them, according to Rabbi Henkin. It seems he is basing this on the advice that these nations (especially Mamre) gave advice to Avraham about circumcision for his Brit Milah (Bereshit 18:1, see Gur Aryeh and Siftei Chachamim there). Rabbi Henkin adds that this merit delayed the conquering of the land because Hashem wasn't going to give the land in stages, as each one of the nations reached their "measure iniquity" one by one, but rather waited until all of them were "full of iniquity", incuding these meritorious ones.
As we know, Hashem pays back good, even the small good of the wicked (see Ramban, Shaar HaGemul).
